# Что является грамматической основой предложения?

Tags: синтаксис

Из трид­ца­ти ушед­ших на фронт мест­ных му­жи­ков вер­ну­лись с войны двое.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Что является грамматической основой предложения?

***Двое из мужиков*** (подл.) ***вернулись*** (сказ).

==================

Гм… А вообще-то… А если вместо "двое" будут названы их имена?

*Из трид­ца­ти ушед­ших на фронт мест­ных му­жи­ков вер­ну­лись с войны лишь Иван да Пётр.*

Вряд ли кто станет утверждать, что здесь подлежащим будет сочетание *"Иван да Пётр из тридцати мужиков".*

ОСНОВА: ***Иван да Пётр*** (подл.) ***вернулись*** (сказ.).

ОСНОВА в исходном предложении: ***двое*** (подл.) ***вернулись*** (сказ.).

Comment: Поручиться пока могу только за выражение "один из нас" - этот пример взят из грамматики (словосочетание со значением избирательности в роли подлежащего".

Comment: Спасибо всем за дискуссию. Жаль девятиклассников, если на экзамене им попадётся подобное задание.

Answer (score 2):

Двое из тридцати мужиков вернулись.

Подлежащим является словосочетание со значением избирательности "двое из тридцати мужиков".

Инверсия слов связана с актуальным членением предложения:

Тема/предмет: Из тридцати ушедших на фронт местных мужиков.

Рема/сообщение: вернулись с войны двое.

Comment: А в этом предложении что будет считаться подлежащим:  _"Из ушед­ших на фронт мест­ных му­жи­ков вер­ну­лись с войны двое"_ ?

Answer (score 0):

Это задание из ОГЭ, из банка ФИПИ. Мнение учителей (обсуждение вне этого сайта) разделилось между "двое из тридцати мужиков вернулись" и "двое вернулись".
Если верно "двое вернулись", то какой член предложения "из тридцати мужиков"? В каком пособии указано, что числительное ОБА может быть  членом предложения  без существительного? Я- за вариант Vera.
Ещё раз обращаю внимание на то,что это задание по школьному курсу...